# creating a vanilla js web-component with separate html and js files

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, native-web-component

While creating vanilla JS web-components, I am trying to figure out a way to keep the template html outside the JS file, preferably in a separate HTML file.

I did look into multiple implementations of native JS web-component implementations notably [here](https://medium.com/samsung-internet-dev/lessons-learned-making-our-app-with-web-components-bf55379cfcda), [single file](https://medium.com/content-uneditable/implementing-single-file-web-components-22adeaa0cd17) and [a very nice writeup here](https://bendyworks.com/blog/native-web-components).

All of the implementations end up putting the html template inside the JS using string literals or similar methods. My question is, is it even possible to make two separate files, for example  `my-component.html` for template and `my-component.js` for JS code?

I have seen this approach working nicely in Aurelia framework, it is very clean and keeps the code where it belongs.

I tried using html imports, by creating a html file for template and including js inside it.

```
<link rel="import" href="my-component.html">
```

that theoretically should work but html imports is already abandoned by browsers.

My second approach, that seems a bit hack to me, but it does work is to 
pull the template html from server in the `connectedCallback`

```
// my-component.js

class MyComponent extends HTMLElement {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        this.initShadowDom();

    }

    async initShadowDom() {
        let shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        shadowRoot.innerHTML = await this.template;
    }

    async fetchData() {
        return await fetch('my-template-url')
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.text();
            });
    }

    get template() {

        return (async () => {
            return await this.fetchData();
        })();
    }
}
customElements.define('my-component', MyComponent);
```

from the server side I simply return pure html

```
// my-component.html

<style>
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons';
@import 'https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.${this.theme}.min.css';
@import 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700';
@import 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css'
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #f7f7f7;
    padding: 1rem;
}
th {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
}
    </style>
<div class="search-list table-responsive">
<table width="100%" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
    <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
        <th width="1rem">
            <input type="checkbox">
        </th>
        <th>
            ID
        </th>
        <th>
            name
        </th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>
            1
        </td>
        <td>
            some name
        </td>

    </tr>

    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Notice how I have skipped the `<template>` tag altogether in the response coming from server, as obviously if I use  `<template>` tag, I will have to use dom parsing to actually put the html into dom.

This does work but it looks so hackish.

Does anyone has a better approach?

Comment: Here is a tool I wrote that uses Rollup to convert your HTML and Locale files into something your code can import and then packages it up into a single file per component: https://www.npmjs.com/package/component-build-tools

Answer (score 1):

You solution is good but you could cut in the Javascript code:

```
class MyComponent extends HTMLElement {

    async connectedCallback() {
        let res = await fetch( 'my-component.html' )

        this.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
            .innerHTML = await res.text()
    }

}
customElements.define( 'my-component', MyComponent )
```

Comment: I wrote a Medium article - with one of the possible solutions
https://roshan-khandelwal.medium.com/web-components-c7aef23fe478

Comment: would this not be a terrible way of handling multiple elements in a page since you do network requests for each html ?

Comment: @DragosPodaru I don't think so now that HTTP/2 and H3 permit to group responses.